# Use BibDesk 1.8 on macOS 11.2.1 Big Sur?

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk, macos

I am trying to use BibDesk 1.8, downloaded from https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io, on macOS Big Sur (11.2.1). I can install the application, but when click to start it, I encounter a dialogue "“BibDesk.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

Is there a known work-around to use BibDesk 1.8 on macOS 11.2.1?

Many thanks!

Comment: Untested, but if you control-click on the application, and choose Open does it give you a dialogue box warning you, but then allowing you to open? This is what worked on older versions of the OS.

Comment: This suggestion solved the problem. Thank you, @AlanMunn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking the application to open it, the first time I control-click BibDesk and choose Open. The dialogue box warns me, but allows me to open the application. Thereafter, I can open the application by simply clicking on it, or launching it with LaunchBar. No dialogue box appears in these subsequent openings of the application.